# How can I prevent from overwriting my changed data during an update in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, updates

I use an extension "bootstrap_package" of "Pizpalue" on TYPO3 (Ver. 11.5.9).

I want to change some content-elements of bootstrap_package, but I have to prevent from overwritting my changed data during a update of the extension.
But I don't know how I can prevent it?

I'll change some codes of some exist files and add some new files in the extension "Bootstrap_package".
For example, HTML-files, CSS-files, ext_tables.sql, typoscript-file, php-file and so on.

What should I do exactly? I'm very thankful if you can answer it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *never* change the code of an extension by yourself: the problem is what you are facing now: it would be impossible to update it without losing your changes.
Instead, you should write **an extension of your own** , which is usually called **"site package"**: this extension will act as the extension that will provide all the configuration for your frontend (and partly for the backend) (you can think of is as your "theme") and will contain

- your TypoScript configuration (both for frontend and backend, for example for the backend layouts)
- the sql files to modify existing tables or add new tables (and relevant php files too)
- the CSS and JS files
- the Fluid templates/layouts/partials files for your pages and content element
- the Fluid template/layout/partials that will overwrite the files of *other extensions* like the ones you find in Boostrap Package
- ...

That would be really hard to write here a full example about this topic; I think you could start reading some documentation here:

- [TYPO3 Getting started tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Index.html)
- [How to install a local extension](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Extensions/Management.html#installing-local-extensions)
- [Site Package tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/main/en-us/Index.html)
- [Fluid Tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Fluid/Introduction.html)

I will just write here a short example based on bootstrap_package

1. Let's say you call your "Site package" extension "site_package"
2. Let's say you want to modify one of the page partials of bootstrap_package:

```
boostrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/Structure/Copyright.html
```

if you look at the bootstrap_package file

```
bootstrap_package/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript
```

you will notice the lines:

```
...
        partialRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
            1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath}
        }
...
```

which means that you can use the TypoScript constant : `page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath` to provide an alternative path for the partials files and the files in this path will *override* the original ones in the bootstrap_package

So, in your site_package extension you will provide the constant (take a look at TYPO3 documentation about how to use TypoScript)

```
page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath = EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
```

And just copy the file you want to override in the folder specified in the TypoScript constant (be sure to keep the subdirectory structure):

```
site_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/Structure/Copyright.html
```

Modify it and you're done

Please note that bootstrap_package provides similar constants to override the Fluid files (partials/templates/layouts) of its content elements.

One last word: if you want, you can start your "site package" extension from scratch or you can use the following site: https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/

To generate a "skeleton" extension with all the basic relevant files and directories; you can even choose to generate a "site package" already tailored to be used together with bootstrap_package!

I hope I answered at least partly to your question; You will also find help on the TYPO3 Slack channel (https://typo3.org/community/meet/chat-slack)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's very helpful for me! But I have two question:

1. Can I use the extension "sitepackage Builder" with the other extension "Pizpalue", "Fluid Styled Content" and "bootstrap_package" without problems? And do you mean the extension "Site Packege" that it is "Sitepackage Builder" or are they different extension?

2. Can I use the "Extension Builder", if I make a new Extension to modify the extension "bootstrap extension"?

Comment: With "site package" I mean an extension that you create and install and contains the configuration of your site.The "sitepackage Builder" I mentioned is not an extension, it's just a service that builds up a "minimal" extension that you can use as a starting point. I don't know the extension "Pizpaule" but I guess that the concepts I wrote could be still valid - You can write your TypoScript and override any TypoScript added by it... sorry I can't be more specific without looking at it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you use bootstrap_package you don't have to include the "fluid styled content" TypoScript as everything is duplicated inside the bootstrap_package itself (but I could be wrong about this point)

Comment: If you really need help starting your journey with TYPO3, consider joining the Slack Group, too

Comment: Thank you for your help! I downloaded the "Sitepackage Builder", configured a constant.typoscript-file and I added a file in my Sitepackage Builder. Unfortunatelly, The code for my changes is not displayed, but the bootstrap content is fine. I'll find out some errors in typoscript-file. But thank you very much for your help. I learned a lot!

Comment: If you've used the "sitepackage builder" to build a package extension compatible with "boostrap_package", it already offers you a constants.typoscript file with the path you need AFAICS. Be sure to activate the extension and load its TypoScript ("Include static (from extension)"). Pay attention to the loading order, too

Comment: Thank you! I could overwrite html from my Sitepackage Builder! Thank you sooooooo much for your help!